# How to create deploy multiple applications in docker container?

Tags: docker

I have docker images for a few tools and the requirement is that based on the user selection, they can select any 2 of the tools and create a container having those tools deployed in it.

As user selects, is it possible to deploy two applications in one container when there are two seperate images for them? If yes, how?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail your selection and build process? Dockerfile examples will be useful to to see how you combine them.

Comment: What do you mean by "two applications"? Can you give examples? If the apps are as simple as Python, Java, Redis, RabbitMQ, etc., there is no need of separate images. A simple base image, e.g. Apline can be used to install these things on it.

Comment: Example like user has option to select 1) jenkins/teamcity  2)ant/maven  and expects the tools selected to get deployed in a container, how to deploy them in one container?...like jenkins and ant / jenkins and maven  ..something like that user expects to be deployed in container.how shud the dockerfiles be built for something like this, when u dont know what option user selects